# Github issue template emoji's not showing up

Tags: github, markdown, emoji

I've made issue templates for my GitHub repo. I saw that it was possible to put emoji's in the title of the template, and thought that would be a fun addition, so I did that. However, my emoji's don't seem to be showing up when actually choosing a template.

This is my template file:

```
name: ":book: Documentatie"
about: Beschrijf informatie die niet klopt of mist in de documentatie
```

The emoji doesn't appear in the choosing, though:
[image: screenshot of issue template]

Which is weird, because when I go to the file in my repo, it looks like this:
[image]

I have no idea what's going wrong here, am I missing something or is this a bug? I've tried refreshing the page without cache, which is really all I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a valid solution and I will thus not mark it as *the* solution, I will say I have found a workaround. There are websites where markdown emoji's are displayed, for example [this one](https://gist.github.com/roachhd/1f029bd4b50b8a524f3c), where you can select the emoji you want, copy it, and paste it in the online editing tool of GitHub. It will then display correctly on the issues page, but it's kind of a hastle and clearly shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: There's a great quick search UTF8(Unicode) emoji search site - https://unicode.party/